# ctypes: pass structure as output param?

Tags: python, ctypes

c:

```
VixError _lib_open(const VixDiskLibConnection connection , 
                  const char *diskPath, uint32 flags, VixDiskLibHandle srcHandle)
{
       VixError vixError = VixDiskLib_Open(connection,diskPath,flags,&srcHandle);
       return vixError;
}

// here srcHandle is output parameter assigned from function call
// call steps:
// VixDiskLibHandle  srcHandle;  //VixDiskLibHandle  srcHandle = NULL;
// VixError err = _lib_open(conn, "<diskpath>", flags, srcHandle);
// do something with   srcHandle
```

I want to pass this `srcHandle` as output param from ctypes

I have declared all structure required  VixDiskLibHandle, VixDiskLibConnection etc...

Python(Ctypes):

```
class struct_VixDiskLibHandleStruct(Structure):
    pass
VixDiskLibHandle = POINTER(struct_VixDiskLibHandleStructure)


src_handle = None #is it correct?
testlib._lib_open(conn, diskpath, openFlag, src_handle)
# use this handle further
disk_info_ptr = testlib.lib_info(src_handle)
```

My disk is opening correctly but when I use sec_handle further, further code is not working.

Am I passing src_handle as ouput param correctly?
or is there any way/need to cast src_handle after testlib._lib_open call?

Comment: I don't know this API, but you will almost certainly have to allocate memory for the structure (i.e. not None) and pass BYREF.

Comment: @cdarke: I'm not sure.  It looks like `_lib_open()` takes the last parameter by value...  If I had to guess, I'd say this is some kind of opaque typedef and OP is supposed to get a handle from somewhere else, or pass `NULL`.

Comment: Either that, or somebody typedef'd a pointer, which is a whole other level of evil.

Comment: @Kevin:  I was going by *I want to pass this srcHandle as output*.

Comment: Yes Kevin it is opaque typedef